# error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘float’ in return

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an array of floating numbers in my function and return the minimum values in an output list but I keep getting this error for some reason and not sure what it is. Any idea?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

float minOfList(float *list1) {
    float lowest = list1[0];
    float lowest2 = 0.0;
    float low_values[] = {};
    int list_length = sizeof(list1)/sizeof(list1[0]);


    for (int item=1; item < list_length; item++) {

    if (list1[item]<lowest) {
        lowest2 = lowest;
        lowest = list1[item];
    }
//        cout << lowest << endl;
//        cout << lowest2 << endl;
    }

    low_values[0] = lowest;
    low_values[1] = lowest2;

    cout << low_values << endl;

    return low_values;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    float mylist[] = {7.0,1.0, 2.5, 3.3,5.5,6,6};

    float values = minOfList(&mylist);
       cout << values << " "<< endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `mylist` is already `float*`. Remove the `&` from `float values = minOfList(&mylist);` and change the function signature to array **or better yet** use `std::vector` or `std::array` for your list of floats.

Comment: you must pass size of list as argument. list1 is a pointer, ```sizeof(list1)``` will return size of pointer and not size of list. You can not get directly size of list that way

Comment: `float low_values[] = {};` This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @dxiv is right. What compiler + version are you using? Those header includes also look archaic to me.

Comment: `minOfList(&mylist)` should not compile, either.

Comment: Take a brave leap  out of the 1980s and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks. Can std::vector<float> array be changed back to regular float array?

Answer (score 2):

## Answer to original question

About your original question, I copy and pasted to [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org) and it gives:

```
<source>:30:12: error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in return
   30 |     return low_values;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Switching to clang:

```
<source>:30:12: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'float' with an lvalue of type 'float [0]'
    return low_values;
           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

This means that your `low_values` array is not a float. In fact it isn't. Why gcc talks about `float*`? Because when you use the name of an array in an expression (sizeof and & excluded) it becomes a pointer to the first element. And a pointer to a float is not a float.

## Real problem with this code

You say: "I'm trying to pass an array of floating numbers in my function". **You can't**. Not in C, nor in C++. The language doesn't allow to have parameters of type array.

In fact your parameter is a pointer to the first element of a sequence of floats. How many? Only the code outside the function can tell it, so you **must** provide the information to your function. It's impossible to know the number of elements pointed to by a pointer.

A first quick fix of your code is this, but it's simplified in order to return the minimum value of the list.

```
#include <iostream>

float minOfList(float *list, int len) 
{
    float lowest = list[0];

    for (int item = 1; item < len; item++) {
        if (list[item] < lowest) {
            lowest = list[item];
        }
    }

    return lowest;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float mylist[] = { 7.0f, 1.0f, 2.5f, 3.3f, 5.5f, 6.f, 6.f };
    int list_length = sizeof(mylist) / sizeof(mylist[0]);

    float value = minOfList(mylist, list_length);

    std::cout << value << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

From here you can expand to returning the two lowest numbers in your list, but remember that you cannot return arrays from functions. Moreover I intentionally avoided all the error checks that you must add to this function.

And this is C, not C++. Please move to C++.

## Moving to C++

Things can open up in a number of ways. Anyway I'll try to stay as conservative as possible and not use algorithms which are ready for you, such as `min_element()` for the single minimum case.

Basic ideas:

- `std::vector<>` instead of the couple pointer and number of elements
- pass by const reference as much as possible
- range based for
- `std::array<>` to return two floats (this could have been done in many other ways)
- initializer list to create the returned array on the fly
- auto to let the compiler specify the type of the variable returned by the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

float minOfList(const std::vector<float>& list)
{
    float lowest = FLT_MAX;
    for (const auto& item : list) {
        if (lowest > item) {
            lowest = item;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}

std::array<float, 2> two_minOfList(const std::vector<float>& list)
{
    float lowest = FLT_MAX;
    float second_lowest = FLT_MAX;
    for (const auto& item : list) {
        if (second_lowest > item) {
            if (lowest > item) {
                second_lowest = lowest;
                lowest = item;
            }
            else {
                second_lowest = item;
            }
        }
    }
    return { lowest, second_lowest };
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<float> mylist = { 7.0f, 1.0f, 2.5f, 3.3f, 5.5f, 6.f, 6.f };

    float value = minOfList(mylist);
    std::cout << "Minimum of list is: " << value << "\n";

    auto tm = two_minOfList(mylist);
    std::cout << "Minimums of list are: [" << tm[0] << ", " << tm[1] << "]\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You missed to answer his original question why he keeps getting the error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘float’ in return.

Comment: @ConstantinoGrana +1 for that

Comment: Thanks, ConstantinoGrana. This was helpful

Comment: @DharmeshPanchal I provided also an example of finding the two lowest values and return them in C++ style. Remember to accept answers if they are ok.